# Android Viewflipper with background animation

Tags: android, viewflipper

is it possible to have a background  animation for the view flipper. I tried it for the second child view of my view flipper project its not working. Is it possible to set the background animation for the childviews , any Idea plz!

I tried with the frame animation but only single Image could able to see on the layout. one more problem is I m getting the same background Image for the two views.This might be the problem I think

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
         R.anim.fade_in));
 mFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
         R.anim.fade_out));
```

Comment: Hi, actually I have two layouts inside the viewflipper and for the second layout I want to add the animation so with out considering Image view how would we use the above functionality. for which layout it will work? if we use the above code.  waiting 4 response

Comment: So you can get the second layout of the ViewFliper by using the following code and then add animation to that layout.          
vf.getChildAt(1).setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
         R.anim.fade_in));     vf is your ViewFlipper object